# domain access module in drupal

Tags: 7, domain-access

I try to set up drupal multisite by using domain access module.we two sites sscsoftweb.com and kumba.sscsoftweb.com.Both are drupal sites which host in shared environment.i install domain access module in sscsoftweb.com. kumba.sscsoftweb.com is subdomain as per installation instruction i remove text followed after /public_html

Then i create a new domain record and create two page called page1 and page2.page1 published in sscsoftweb.com similarly page2 publish in kumba.sscsoftweb.com.i set the homepage for kumba.sscsoftweb.com is node/2.

the problem is when i hit kumba.sscsoftweb.com it automatically redirect to sscsoftweb.com homepage not to node/2. is there any thing i miss.kindly suggest me how to fix this issue.

thanks..

Answer (score 1):

I played with the domain access module and I remember I had to set the cookie domain in settings.php to ".example.com", in your case ".sscsoftweb.com".
But I'm not sure this will fix your problem.